# Should Tax Identification Number be INT on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I am making a database, and to identify a client, their Tax Identification Number will be the **Primary Key.**
**
Should the Tax Identification Number be VARCHAR, even though it's just numbers?**

I know things like phone numbers are more like addresses than numbers, and therefore should be VARCHAR.

I am not sure if the Tax Identification Number should be treated the same way, and I need to know these things before I work on the database since I am required to make a Entity Relationship Diagram of the database.

Comment: ERD is not a part of UML.

Comment: You dont provide any examples of what this quantity looks like - what you use it for, do you join it to other existing varchar data etc. If it's truly just a number and you need to treat it as a number then *int* all the way.

Comment: There is nothing in the question or your profile to indicate where you are , include that and someone from your territory might provide a useful insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are sure it's purely made up of numbers , why not use INT, which takes less disk space and less resource to index ? It's not like phone numbers , which sometimes may contain punctuation marks like hyphen. e.g 0064-337881

By the way, if data masking is required.  An implicit convert is automatically performed so the INT type is cast into string type. e.g.
`select insert(tax_id, 2 , 3, '***') from testtable;`

result:

1***56

7***12

9***07

Answer (score 0):

In the USA, Tax Identification Numbers are 9 digits, and the first digit is 9. So if you store this as numbers only, it fits within a signed 32-bit integer, which supports values up to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or 2147483647.

But TIN values are commonly formatted with hyphens after the third and fifth digit, i.e. `XXX-XX-XXXX`. An Employer Identification Number (EIN) is commonly formatted as `XX-XXXXXXX` with a hyphen after the second digit.

I would therefore use a VARCHAR(11). This allows the common formatting.